# Active Collab User Invite API Script Error email_addresses not found in array

Tags: json, api, activecollab

In this post is explained how to invite people via API:

[Active Collab send Email after User create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47353613/active-collab-send-email-after-user-create)

I created my auth Token and tried out this API/JSON Request with Powshell:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Headers $headers -Uri "https://pmo.lukad.net/api/v1/users/invite"  -Body '{email_addresses:["webmaster@lukad.com"],role:"Member"}'
```

Iam getting this Error:

```
Script failed! Last error: {"type":"InvalidParamError","message":"'email_addresses' not found in array","code":0,"file":"\/var\/www\/pmo\/activecollab\/5.13.133\/angie\/functions\/general.php
","line":826,"trace":"#0 /var/www/pmo/activecollab/5.13.133/modules/system/controllers/UsersController.class.php(134): array_required_var(Array, 'email_addresses'.....
```

Iam not sure what is wrong in this script. I tried out allready without clinches []

Answer (score 0):

That body does not look like a valid JSON. JSON is pretty simple, but also pretty strict. JSON parser in PHP is never trying to fix the content, it just throws an error (returns `false` to be more specific).

Here is a valid JSON:

```
{"email_addresses":["webmaster@lukad.com"],"role":"Member"}
```

You can use services like https://jsonlint.com to validate JSON if you are writing it manially, to avoid this type of errors.

Comment: Ok Thanks - solved it in my Powershell script just use the right Quoting Rules.@"{"email_addresses":["webmaster@lukad.com"],"role":"Member"}"@

Comment: Great. Please upvote and accept the answer if it helped you.